# Submitting form data to database?

Tags: php, wordpress

Does anyone have any idea how I can use a form to submit data within a custom metabox? I know wordpress already creates a form for the metabox hook, so most likely I dont need a form, if that is indeed true let me show you how the meta box adds data to the DB..

This adds input data into the wp_postmeta table

```
$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $field['id'], !$field['multiple'] );
```

Its used in field types, ex. text, textarea etc etc

```
   switch ( $field['type'] ) {

            case 'text':
                echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', '' !== $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" />','<p class="moon_metabox_description">', $field['desc'], '</p>';
                break;
            case 'text_small':
                echo '<input class="moon_text_small" type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', '' !== $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" /><span class="moon_metabox_description">', $field['desc'], '</span>';
                break;
}
```

For each field I can only use `$meta` once I am trying to create a field type similar to this, here is a rough idea...

```
<?php case 'My_Form_Data': ?>

   <div class="width-option">  
      <input type="text" name="width" value="<?php echo $meta['properties']['width'] ?>" class="input">
   </div>

   <div class="bg-color-option">
      <input type="text" name="backgroundcolor" value="<?php echo $meta['properties']['backgroundcolor'] ?>" class="input color">
   </div>

<?php break; ?>
```

The end goal is just to populate the `meta_value` column with an array of data, ex:

[image: meta_value]

This data was entered manually, I need to integrade it with a metabox so I can use `$post->ID` and assign the data accordingly.

Comment: Have you read: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta . This could be your solution

Comment: its actually helpful. this may help me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this tutorial: http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/